# SceneKit: How to constrain movement of a node to one axis locally, not the entire world

Tags: ios, swift, macos, constraints, scenekit

It's very easy to prevent movement of a node in one axis (X, Y, or Z) being moved by other forces with an SCNTransformConstraint.positionConstraint in world space as follows:

```
let zPosition = node.position.z

let strafingConstraint = SCNTransformConstraint.positionConstraint(inWorldSpace: true, with: {(_ node: SCNNode, _ position: SCNVector3) -> SCNVector3 in
         localPosition = position
         localPosition.z = zPosition
         return localPosition
})

node.constraints = [strafingConstraint];
```

However, this constrains this in world space. What do I do if I want to just make the node no longer move in its local Z axis, regardless of its orientation, so it can only move in its local X and Y axes, what do I do? Is there a way to use the .convertPosition(*:from:) or .convertPosition(*:to:) functions to do this? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

With this constraint myNode only moves along the x and y axes and is constrained to zPosition along the z axis:

```
let zAxisConstraint = SCNTransformConstraint.positionConstraint(inWorldSpace: true) { node, position
    in
    let newPosition = SCNVector3(position.x, position.y, zPosition)
    return newPosition
}

myNode.constraints = [zAxisConstraint]
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be an alternative approach to fix a node to a specific axis without using a SCNConstraint.

Use the `updateAtTime` delegate function to adjust the z-position of your node within each frame:

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval) {
    node.position.z = 0.0 // or wherever you want to have it
}
```

*(If your node has a physics body attached to it, you should only alter it's position when the body type is = `.kinematc`)*

Comment: First, thank you very much for your response, it's very much appreciated! Second, I think then that my question wasn't clear enough. To clarify: The body is kinematic, is being controlled by user input to move. The body isn't directly facing a specific axis (X, Y, or Z) and I wanted to restrict its movement forwards & backwards (such as along its local Z direction, so that it can only translate locally along its local X & Y coordinates) in relation to the node itself (it may be facing an direction oblique to an axis). TL\DR: How do I restrict the node's movement in local space?

Comment: I believe it's a bit misleading to say you shouldn't alter the position of a node whose physics body is `static` or `dynamic`. I would just say that 1) there's a performance penalty, and 2) you must call `node.physicsBody?.resetTransform()` after setting the position, as documented here -> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnphysicsbody/1514782-resettransform